# VSCODE Log for Replay Debugger Inconsistent with current code

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, vs-code, apex-replay-debugger

After pushing code, setting breakpoints, enabling Log for Replay, running tests and Retrieving Debug logs

When I step through, the pointer seems to be pointing at phantom code lines, and seems as though the code running on the server is different from my local code, although I have verified that it is the same by opening in Developer Console.

At first I thought I had not pushed the latest version or retrieved the latest logs, but I have repeated this several times now and still the debug logs appear to miss match my latest code.

Any thought ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Can be caused by using old logs. Try to rerun VSCODE Get Apex Logs
- Can be caused by Retrieval of outdated logs due to 'Turn On Debug for Replay' failure.
  Try deleting the current active Log through the portal Setup > Debug Logs then rerun VSCODE 'Turn On Debug for Replay', execute code and 'Get Apex Debug Log' and reattempt Debug

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).